# unable to resolve dependency tree error for creating new angular project

Tags: angular, npm

so today I wanted to create a new Angular project using the command `ng new <projectname>` and I got this error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: project-name@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

---

I literally tried everything, I updated `npm`, installed `Angular cli` again, download and installed `node` again, `npm audit`, and a lot of other things but nothing happened.

Also as you can see error told me to use the command with `--force`, I tried but nothing happened, and with `--legacy-peer-deps`, I get the error as unknown option.

What is bothering me the most is that everything was working completely right last night and I changed nothing at all but suddenly I'm getting this error today.

Comment: Just update the angular-cli at first then ng new appName this worked for me

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Open the folder you create with ng new  and open the `package.json` file. In `devDependencies` change the version of "jasmine-core" `3.6.0` to `3.8.0` and "karma-jasmine-html-reporter" from `1.7.0` to `1.6.0` and save it. Then go back to Terminal and go to your project and run `npm install`. Now it works and you can run `ng serve`.

**Edit 2021**

```
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0"
```

Comment: Versions can be different based on what version of Angular/CLI or NPM is installed. I had to change the versions again after changing NPM version.

Comment: I've been having this problem for a while, but I was already at jasmine-core 3.7.1. Instead, I had to use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` to get anywhere. Today I found jasmine-core 3.8.0 available, and that finally fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Yes. Worked for me as well.

Comment: Any idea if this is something that can be changed/fixed on my end to prevent this, or is it a cli bug? Pretty bad when you have to google workarounds just to create an Angular hello world project.

Comment: Still working in 2022

Comment: It works form me, thanks, but I think that errors like that are not accepatable :)

Comment: This seems to have worked for me, too. But still, I literally just created a new project and didn't change anything about it, so why did I get this error to begin with?!

Comment: It is really a shame to get an error, you are no responsible of, at the start of a project ! And really horrible for beginners !

Comment: I agree, this is very annoying trying to work in Angular projects. I'm doing some new learning projects and getting errors like this constantly. Why don't they give developers an option to resolve these automatically? Like "you need to upgrade jasmine-core dependencies, upgrade now? Y/N"

Comment: Exact Same issue , and solution work like a magic

Answer (score 40):

Mine is a temporary solution for angular-cli v11.2.12 based on @david-Öztürk answer and on [this angular-cli github issue discussions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20719) and on [its merged fix](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/dd3eb33170b2f7070b8e2b3d81219da60e6454c0).

By executing the steps listed on @david-Öztürk answer I was still getting the same error. And also the fix is more conservative than the proposed solution. I hope it helps someone else:

Run the Angular project creation without automatic npm packages installation:

```sh
ng new --skip-install <project-name>
```

Enter project directory:

```sh
cd <project-name>
```

Edit `package.json` and change this...

```js
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
```

...to this:

```js
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
```

Manually install npm packages:

```sh
npm install
```

**Note: The version 1.5.0 here was used because it is the version that appears in the error message and we are tying to be more conservative here. Please adapt the version according to your specific necessity. For newer projects the version 1.7.0 may be more suited but it can change with time. Read your specific error message in order to chose what better addresses your specific case.**

Comment: adding the "~" to 1.5.0 worked for me. I am updated to angular version 12.2.4. I had to throw out my package-lock.json first. a silly workaround but what you gonna do. thanks Iogui!

Comment: @IanPostonFramer I belive that if you run `npm install` after manually changing your `package.json` file it updates your `package-lock.json` for you. Anyway, the first step with the `--skip-install` flag should not generate a package-lock.json avoiding this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861938/981766

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and I solved it with reinstalling nodeJs 14.16.1
but I had to change the version of npm manually with the command

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.12
```

After of course, I tested the modifications by creating a project

```
ng new <MyProjet>
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the issue with latest **NPM 7.12.0** and the latest **Node 16.1.0(Current Version)**

In my case I followed the below steps -

1. Uninstall Node
2. Re-Install the Latest Node (`LTS: 14.16.1`)

   - Which will install the latest `NPM : 6.14.12`
3. Run the `ng new my-app`

Comment: thanks! works like a charm. I use nvm, so my steps were: "nvm install --lts" then reinstall angular "npm install -g @angular/cli" and it worked perfectly

Comment: This solution is perfect. Just remember to remove the npm and node folders from `%userprofile%/AppData/Roaming` after running the uninstall step. This way you can be sure that you've fully deleted node & npm.

Answer (score 9):

If you are still facing this problem then try to make sure your `package.json` have all versions matching other supporting library versions. The `jasmine-core` had to be greater than **3.8** with `karma-jasmine-html-report` **1.7+**

here is how my devDependecies looked inside package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

What it worked for me was manually update package.json to look like this

```
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0"
```

and then I tried

```
npm install
```

but didn't work either so I tried

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

and then everything worked again I was able to do
`npm start` as usual

Answer (score 5):

install node, if you do not have it or update to the newest version:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

update your npm:
***npm install npm@latest -g***

optional :
***npm i update-node***

This will update angular to its newest version:
***npm install -g @angular/cli***
Create a new angular project:
***ng new projectName***
Change directory the projectName:
***cd projectName***
Serve the project
***ng s***

Comment: Perfect solution for my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can update angular cli globally: `npm update @angular/cli -g`

Comment: This is the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

They have released `Karma Jasmine` html reporter few hours ago. This maybe what is breaking the code.
 [The update is most likely the cause.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter)

You should change the `package.json` and get the older version of the `Karma Jasmine` [older version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/v/1.5.4)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using this command inside my project directory:

1. npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular --force
2. npm audit fix --force

then I ran my project using "ng serve"

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `package.json` in your project folder.

"jasmine-core": "~3.7.0" to "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0" to "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0"

After run `npm install` in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Error Details** after doing
`ng new my-app`

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0

**Fix Details**

1. `sudo npm install -g npm@7.13.0` => updated npm from `7.10.0` to `7.13.0`
2. Only changed `"jasmine-core"` from `3.6.0` to `3.7.1` i.e `"jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",` in package.json
3. `npm install`

After this found no issues and I was able to do `ng build` and `ng serve`.

Other settings I left as it was :
`"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",`
`"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",`

Answer (score 0):

Does not help update npm nor node.js. Strange error, strange error mesages. Does help to update package.json - change version of something 'jasmine' - "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0". I don't know what is it for, but it make problems.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today, after updating `npm` to `latest` - currently `8.5.3`. THen I simply run `ng new <my-new-project>` from command-line, adding `Angular Route` I answered `y`, and selected `SCSS`. `ng` did his thing and I got the error, only different versions:

Angular 12

- No `jasmine-core` - In the error states `"jasmine-code@3.7.1"` and I
  need `"jasmine-code@>=3.8"`)
- No `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` (error
  states `"@^1.5.0"` and I need `"@1.7.0"`)
- Checked `node_modules` and
  `packages.json`- no mention, nor trace, of those.

After reading this issue and answers. I decided to update my `Angular` to the `latest` and run `ng -g i angular-cli@latest` and I received an error that the file `ng.cmd` already exists in folder `{Windows-users-username-folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd` - I deleted the file. The 2nd time I run the update of `Angular` I received the same error on file `ng.` (deleted it) and the 3rd time the error was on `ng.ps1` (deleted it three). Then update of `Angular` was successful. Then I run `ng new <my-new-project>` and it was successful as well.

By the way, in my new project's `packages.json` I see:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1", 
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38", 
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13","ts-node": "1.2.1", "tslint": "^4.3.0", 
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
}
```

Nothing even remotely similar to what was stated in the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try on this

```
 npx -p @angular/cli@12.0.0 --legacy-peer-deps  ng new  angular12App
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

If you're still experiencing this after trying some/all of the above options, Just downgrade npm version from 7 to 6: npm install -g npm@6