# I'm not able to initialize my Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to initialize and create my Angular app using `ng new my-app`, but while creating new app I received below error:

["The Schematic workflow failed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhcVq.png)

I've also tried updating node & npm version, but no luck.

If anyone has any idea regarding this issue, that would be a great help!

Cheers!

Comment: Can you let us know the Node, Angular-CLI and NPM version?

Comment: what libraries did you add to your project ? can you show your dependencies defined in `package.json` file?

Comment: What does "initialize my Angular App" mean?  How are you creating a new app?

Comment: @MBB - Below are the versions I'm using:

Node: v14.16.1
npm: v7.12.0
Angular CLI: 11.2.12

Comment: @FilipKováč
I just created new angular project just now, and i ran into this error. I have added nothing as of now. The problem is, node_modules folder is not there in angular structure.

Comment: @NimishSrivastav - Can you check these steps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433893/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-for-creating-new-angular-project/67451478#67451478

Comment: @MBB, earlier I had v6 of npm and v12 of node, so I updated it to latest version (which is what i mentioned above). Then tried to create new angular project, but the error was same. With older version, error was same

Comment: Can you just add NPM version to 6.14.12 keeping node version as is   v14.16.1. I have followed these steps and it is working

Comment: @MBB, yes it did work!
Thanks a lot!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, This looks like the issue with latest ***NPM 7.12.0*** and the latest Node ***16.1.0***(Current Version)

In my case I followed the below steps -

1. Uninstall Node
2. Re-Install the Latest Node `(LTS: 14.16.1)`

   - Which will install the latest `NPM : 6.14.12`
3. Run the `ng new my-app`