# Angular: The Schematic workflow failed. See above

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, angular-cli

```
CREATE firstapp/package.json (1209 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/README.md (1018 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/tsconfig.json (783 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/tslint.json (3185 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/.browserslistrc (703 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/karma.conf.js (1425 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/tsconfig.app.json (287 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/tsconfig.spec.json (333 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/index.html (294 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/polyfills.ts (2830 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/app/app.component.html (24955 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1063 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/app/app.component.ts (212 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/e2e/protractor.conf.js (904 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/e2e/tsconfig.json (274 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (659 bytes)
CREATE firstapp/e2e/src/app.po.ts (274 bytes)
| Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: firstapp@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\vishn\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vishn\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-10T00_27_07_509Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.12
Node: 16.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.12 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.12 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.12 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    11.2.12 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             11.2.12 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.1102.12 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.3 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
```

I tried to create new Angular project and got this error. I pasted my error here and the versions of angular and its dependency used (ng version). I installed Node.js using installer and angular cli using using cmd command. But I can't create a new project(ng new project-name) Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an error in angular-cli by some outdated packages , it has been solved in their repository in github , but they haven't published it yet to npmjs , you can solve it in 2 ways:

1. using "--legacy-peer-deps --force" when installing packages
2. updating package.json at "jasmine" like in the latest commit in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/b34ed5c4007f9ef08b370219081b4d23f9f24fb8

this is an open issue for this error on angular-cli github repo https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20719

Answer (score 2):

update or new install @angular/cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 2):

### I face the same issue and but I solve it with the following steps

### 1- I install the latest node version from https://nodejs.org/en/

### 2- uninstall the cli by the following command

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
```

### 3- clean the cache by the following command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

##### & verify by

```
npm cache verify
```

### 4- now run the following command

npm install -g @angular/cli

### 5- now created new project.It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can also Downgrade npm from 7 to 6 using `npm install -g npm@6` to fix this probleme

if you have another problem during the instalation, delete npm and npm-cache in: `\AppData\Roaming` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433893/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-for-creating-new-angular-project), it's the same issue.

> Open the folder you create with ng new and open the package.json file. In devDependencies change the version of "jasmine-core" 3.6.0 to 3.7.1 and "karma-jasmine-html-reporter" from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 and save it. Than go back to Terminal and go to your project and run npm install. Now it works und you can run ng serve.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, so I chose a newer node version using n library, like here: https://nkaushik.com/nodejs/nodejs-version-manager-n/

then I updated my angular version with :

```
install -g @angular/cli
```

oh, and don't forget to turn off your VPN

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

There is a workaround for starting a new Angular project:

`ng new project --skip-install`

`cd project`

`npm install` (or if that fails `npm install --force`)

I discovered this within the comments of the open issue for this error on angular-cli github repo  which *Ammar M Mashfj* linked to in their answer: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20719#issuecomment-835810313

Answer (score 0):

The problem with our enviornment was that the version of node we were using was incompatible. We had v19 and it needes 10.13.x/12.11.x or later minor. See this [referenced chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258560/6569899).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Apparently npm just didn't have access to these packages, which was why it didn't find them. The following did it for me:

```
sudo ng new firstapp
```