# I have error in Angular/CLI when i want to create new project

Tags: angular

i have an error when i run : ng new project, i had also tried npm cache verify and force clean but it doesn't work, i tried to uninstall nodeJs but it still the same problem

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Ziad Bougrine\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ziad Bougrine\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-11T16_13_12_450Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYjU8.png)

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as an image :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to resolve dependency tree error for creating new angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433893/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-for-creating-new-angular-project)

Comment: I had the same problem.  I opened `package.json` and changed the Jasmine core dependency to version `3.8.0` and ran `npm i` again and the project compiled and could be served.