# log4js-node-DEP0004 - Deprecation warning in Angular 12 karma unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, log4js-node

I'm getting the following deprecation warning when running unit tests in a brand new Angular 12 application:

> (node:14940) [log4js-node-DEP0004] DeprecationWarning: **Pattern %d{DATE} is deprecated due to the confusion it causes when used. Please use %d{DATETIME} instead.**

[image]

`why log4js` prompts `"karma" depends on it`. The warning itself is clear as to what should be done but there are two key missing pieces of information:

- it doesn't say when/if the old syntax will stop working
- it doesn't provide a workaround (other than forking `karma` and replacing the deprecated syntax with the new one - which I'm definitely not going to do).

Downgrading `log4js` to an earlier version, which doesn't output the warning, using `forceResolutions` doesn't seem like a good idea, especially since I've found a few github threads related to vulnerabilities in it, although karma [doesn't seem to be affected](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3732).

**The question**: are there actionable paths for not getting the warning, or is *"and now we wait"* (for a `karma` update) the only option?

**Note:** I've also asked it on [karma's repo](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3753).

Comment: Worked for me but first a needed to resolve some dependecies [Used this link to help me first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433893/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-for-creating-new-angular-project),

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Got the fix from `karma` maintainers:

Update `karma` (in `package.json > devDependencies.karma`) to `^6.3.12`.

Warnings gone. Well done, `karma`. That was fast!