# I'm getting the following deprecation warning when running unit tests in a brand new Angular 11 application:

Tags: angular, unit-testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyLqj.png)

This is the error that I was getting

Unit Testing (This type  of error occurs when I run ng test)

Comment: Angular 11 isn't brand new. Angular 14 is the newest version. Can you remove the image of the error and add it as text, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from `karma` (it uses `log4js` under the hood). The solution is to update `karma` to at least `^6.3.12.` as found here: [log4js-node-DEP0004 - Deprecation warning in Angular 12 karma unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841924/log4js-node-dep0004-deprecation-warning-in-angular-12-karma-unit-tests)