# Angular ng new Fails with 'ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree' Due to Jasmine-Core Version Conflict

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, jasmine

I'm able to create an Angular project using ng new, but I'm encountering a dependency conflict warning involving jasmine-core versions:

Error Message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
...
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.5.0
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
```

The project is created, but I'm concerned about potential issues due to this conflict.

Steps Tried:

- Deleted node_modules and reinstalled dependencies.
- Tried different Angular CLI and Node.js versions.
- Cleared npm cache.

How can I resolve this dependency conflict without using --force or --legacy-peer-deps?
Is there a way to ensure compatible jasmine-core versions during project creation to prevent this warning?
Are there known issues or workarounds for this conflict within specific Angular CLI or Node.js versions?

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433893/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-for-creating-new-angular-project